# How to align the text of a merged td to a certain cell in the previous row in an HTML table

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML tables. I have a table as shown below. Is it possible to align the left of the value6 in the second tr to the left of the cell containing value3, which the third cell in the previous row? I tried `style="padding-left:185px"` as fixed padding, but it didn't give the desired result, especially in a responsive page design.

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="form_label">value1</td>
        <td class=" form_label">value2</td>
      <td class="form_label">value3</td>
        <td class=" form_label">value4</td>
      <td class="form_label">value5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=" 5 " class="form_label " style="padding-left:185px ">value6</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might not be possible using css because of diverse size of devices. However, if you would be ok with splitting the second row into 2 cols, it might work. Try this code.

And also, you are missing the closing quote mark in your classes in all `td` in first row.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="form_label">value1</td>
    <td class="form_label">value2</td>
    <td class="form_label">value3</td>
    <td class="form_label">value4</td>
    <td class="form_label">value5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="3" class="form_label">value6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: @Kim Happy coding